# Get rate and currency of a JIRA worklog via RESTful API

Tags: python, rest, api, jira, tempo

I tried to get the rate of my JIRA worklogs with a python script. I have the Tempo Timesheet plugin with API for base, timesheets, accounts and teams. Everything is up to date. This is my prefered process:

1. Get worklogs

   ```
   /rest/api/latest/worklogs?[params]
   ```
2. Get account key of worklog over the issue

   ```
   /rest/api/latest/issue/[issue_key]
   ```
3. Get account data

   ```
   /rest/tempo-accounts/1/account/key/[account_key]
   ```
4. Get member role

   ```
   /rest/tempo-teams/2/team/1/member
   ```

(loop beans and search for member of the worklog)

5. Now I have the account key and the member role id. Which API call helps me to get the related rate and currency?

In the docs is written, that the call

```
/rest/tempo-accounts/1/account/key/[account_key]
```

should response the ratetable id:

https://tempo.io/doc/accounts/api/rest/latest/#1463521625

With this information, I could extract everything from

```
/rest/tempo-accounts/1/ratetable/global/
```

In my case, this doens't work. There is no ratetable entry in the account response. Could this be a permission issue? Does anyone of you know a smarter way to get the rate and currency of a worklog?

Comment: Do you have any Rates set up in Tempo at all? Note that you will need *Tempo Rate Administrators* permission to view and add Rates.

Comment: Yes I have set up multiple rate tables with some rates in Jira. I used the rate table functions for a long time in Tempo and inside Jira, it works. I built a workaround, but it has a very bad style: 
1. read in all rate tables
2. Get the scope of each rate table (=list of account ids)
3. Search in the scope for the account id, I got by the issue.
4. If I found a match -> go through all rates of the ratetable and compare the link type with "TEAM_ROLE" and the link id with the member role id.
5. When there is a match, I have the amount and the currency.

This costs lots of http requests..